# Electric Field and Direction of Field

Tags: definite-integrals, physics, electromagnetism

I want to measure the magnitude, and the direction of the electric field at point P induced by a rod that has a charge of $-22.0\mathrm{\mu C}$. The problem has been accurately dimensioned. The distance of the rod to point P has to be calculated, because the dimensions given where to the centroid of the rod. My ultimate problem is how do I know the direction of the field? Here is my work for the problem.
\begin{equation}\vec{E}=\int\frac{k\ dq}{r^2}\hat{r} \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\frac{dq}{dx}=\frac{Q}{L}=\lambda \end{equation}
\begin{align}E&=\int_{.29}^{.43} \frac{k\lambda}{x^2}dx\\ &=\frac{kQ}{L}[-\frac{1}{x}]\Bigg|_{0.29}^{.43}\\&=-1.59\times 10^6 \frac{N}{C} \end{align}
Can anyone please help explain why the answer is that the electric field is point to the right according to my physics professors answer sheet?
[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>First of all, if I read the figure right, the limits of integration are $36\pm 0.14/2$, not $0.36\pm 0.14/2$. But this will only change the numerical value.</s>

In your first equation, where you define the electric field,you have two quantities that will inform you about the direction of the electric field. $\hat r$ is a vector from the charge creating the electric field toward the point where you measure the electric field. So in your case $\hat r$ points to the left. The other quantity of interest is the charge. Yours is negative, so the electric field will point in a direction opposite to $\hat r$. Therefore, in this problem the electric field points to the right.

If you want a physical intuition, the direction of the electric field is the direction of the force acting on a **positively** charged particle. A positive charge at $P$ is attracted by a negatively charged rod, so the direction of the electric field is to point from $P$ to the negatively charged rod

Comment: I am so sorry its 36 cm, so .36 m

Comment: Than all you need from my reply is the direction. Ignore the first paragraph.